Bottom Navigation Not Changing Selected Button
Can anyone help me how to fix this? I am new in Java.
When Bottom Navigation button is clicked, It should active the menu. But only home button is active all time. Clicking Others Button Changing the active color for 1 sec. After 1 sec Active color returns to 1st Button.
public class BottomNavigation {

    public static void setupBottomNavigation(final Activity activity, final BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView) {

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bookList) {
                startActivity(activity, BookListActivity.class);
                bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bookList); //This line is not working
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {
                startActivity(activity, MainActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.writerList) {
                startActivity(activity, WriterActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.libraryList) {
                startActivity(activity, LibraryActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.contactUs) {
                startActivity(activity, ContactActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private static void startActivity(@NonNull Activity activity, Class<?> cls) {
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), cls));
        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}




On every item click you are starting new activity, you have BottomNavigationView in every activity?

Yes! I have same BottomNavigationView in every activity.

As a quick workaround you can set selectedItemId before setOnItemSelectedListener. I would suggest adding selectedItemId parameter into your BottomNavigation#setupBottomNavigation and then you can use bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(selectedItemId); to set selected item.
public class BottomNavigation {

    public static void setupBottomNavigation(
            final Activity activity,
            final BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView,
            int selectedItemId //Added this parameter
    ) {
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(selectedItemId); //Set selected item


        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bookList) {
                startActivity(activity, BookListActivity.class);
                bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bookList); //This line is not working
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {
                startActivity(activity, MainActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.writerList) {
                startActivity(activity, WriterActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.libraryList) {
                startActivity(activity, LibraryActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.contactUs) {
                startActivity(activity, ContactActivity.class);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private static void startActivity(@NonNull Activity activity, Class<?> cls) {
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), cls));
        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}


The Problem
BottomNavigationView is not meant to be used with activities, in your code you are creating new BottomNavigationView in every activity with default selected item 0. That's why it looks like items are not being selected, because the activity get replaced with another one.
Now you can use the workaround but for your next application you should use single activity with bottom navigation and fragments for the items. There are lots of free resources and tutorials how to do that, this one looks good - Bottom Navigation Bar in Android.

Now I am using fragment instead of activity. Thanks!
